# How to create thread for function with return type in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Below is my code:
main_clss.py:

```
ressampledadjusted,resampledldf,ultiCalc,Reserve_val = mackmethod_obj.sampled(noofsimulation,adjustedscaled,cumulativetriangle,LDFTringle,variancetriangle)
```

In above code I just calling method called sampled() with the help of object of mack method class (mackmethod_obj). Sampled() present in mack method class. I calling sampled()n with argument 4 arguments like noofsimulation,adjustedscaled,cumulativetriangle,LDFTringle,variancetriangle and this sampled() returns 3 type of result's like ressampledadjusted,resampledldf,ultiCalc,Reserve_val.
Here my problem is how can use multithreading concept for sampled() which present in mack method class. Because it have return type.

mack method.py

```
 def sampled(self,noofsimulation,AdscaledDF,cumulativeTriangleDf,LdftriangleDf,varianceDf):
        Reserve_val = []               
        iter_count=0
        while (iter_count < noofsimulation):
        #Getting Resampled Adjusted Scaled Residuals Triangle    
            randomdf = AdscaledDF.copy()
            choices = randomdf.values[~pd.isnull(randomdf.values)] 
            randomdf = randomdf.applymap(lambda x: np.random.choice(choices) if not pd.isnull(x) else x)      

        #Getting Resampled LDF's Triangle'
            cumdf = cumulativeTriangleDf.iloc[:, :-1][:-2].copy()
            ldfdf = LdftriangleDf.iloc[:, :-1].copy()
            ResampledDF = randomdf.copy()
            for colname4, col4 in ResampledDF.iteritems():
                ResampledDF[colname4] = (ResampledDF[colname4] * (varianceDf[colname4].iloc[-1]/(cumdf[colname4]**0.5)))+ldfdf[colname4].iloc[-1]
       
        #SUMPRODUCT:
            sumPro = ResampledDF.copy()
            #cumdf = cumdf.iloc[:, :-1]
            for colname5,col5 in sumPro.iteritems():
                sumPro[colname5] = (sumPro[colname5])*cumdf[colname5]
            sumPro = sumPro.append(pd.Series(sumPro.sum(), name='SUMPRODUCT'))

        #SUM(OFFSET):
            f = lambda x: x.iloc[:cumdf.index.get_loc(x.last_valid_index())].sum()
            sumOff = cumdf.dropna(how='all', axis=1).apply(f)

        #Weighted avg:
            Weighted_avg = sumPro.loc['SUMPRODUCT']/sumOff
            ResampledDF = ResampledDF.append(pd.Series(Weighted_avg, name='Weighted Avg'))
            ResampledDF.loc['Weighted Avg'] = ResampledDF.loc['Weighted Avg'].replace(0, 1)
            ResampledDF.loc['Weighted Avg'] = ResampledDF.loc['Weighted Avg'].replace(np.nan, 1)
            c = ResampledDF.iloc[1][::-1].replace(np.inf, np.nan).dropna().cumprod()
            ResampledDF = ResampledDF.append(c.rename('CDF'))
        
        #Getting Calculation of ultimates:
            s = cumulativeTriangleDf.iloc[:, :][:-2].copy()
            ultiCalc = pd.DataFrame()
            ultiCalc['Paid']= s['Total'] 
            ultiCalc['CDF'] = np.flip(ResampledDF.loc['CDF'].values)
            ultiCalc['Ultimate'] = ultiCalc['Paid']*ultiCalc['CDF']
            ultiCalc['Reserves'] = ultiCalc['Ultimate']-ultiCalc['Paid']
            ultiCalc = ultiCalc.append(pd.Series(ultiCalc.sum(), name='Total'))
            iter_count+=1
            Reserve_val.append(ultiCalc['Reserves']) 
            
        return randomdf,ResampledDF,ultiCalc,Reserve_val
```

Above is the code which present in sampled() method. From class called mac method. Please explain me how to create multi-threading concept for above.

Comment: To share data between threads you can use class attributes, global variables or queues, depending on your setup. If you can't change .sampled, just create a wrapper function that simply calls .sampled inside.

Comment: Can you please explain with any example? @VascoLudovico

Answer (score 0):

To share data between threads you can use class attributes, global variables or queues, depending on your setup. If you can't change .sampled, just create a wrapper function that simply calls .sampled inside. Here's an example using class attributes:

```
import threading

def dummy(arg):
    return 'new_'+arg

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,):
        self.container=None

    def wrapper_method(self,arg):
        self.container=dummy(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass=MyClass()
    dummy_thread=threading.Thread(target=myclass.wrapper_method,args=('test_label',))
    dummy_thread.start()
    print(myclass.container)
```

The result from the dummy function is stored in the class attribute container. Here I assumed the dummy function was an external function which you would prefer no to integrate in your class.